# php adding multiple uploads form

Tags: php

I have a form to upload pictures. I got how to allow multiple files but I am not sure how to edit the php to allow multiple pictures to be sent. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```html
<?php

 //Settings
$max_allowed_file_size = 100; // size in KB
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");
//Validations
if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
{
  $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
}
//------ Validate the file extension -----
$allowed_ext = false;
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
{
  if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
  {
    $allowed_ext = true;
  }
}
if(!$allowed_ext)
{
  $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
  " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
}

  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      header("Location: pages/thank-you-phone/");
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set anything to allow multiple pictures upload in php.

but you have to take care of:

Add this to an htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value post_max_size 200M
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
   php_value memory_limit 300M
   php_value max_execution_time 259200
   php_value max_input_time 259200
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

---

HTML:

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP:

```
//$files = array_filter($_FILES['upload']['name']); //something like that to be used before processing files.

// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {

  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a file path
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps out!